# How to solve $x+(x\cdot\frac{20}{100})=600$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was solving a puzzle, and finally I got this equation as the result but I couldn't solve it.

$$x+\left(x\times\left(\frac{20}{100}\right)\right)=600$$

How to solve this equation?
Please provide a step by step solution.

Comment: You've gotta show your own work first!

Comment: Hint: $x$ is a common factor on the left hand side.

Comment: Considering the way you formulated a puzzle to an equation so, you could solve your own equation!

Comment: I can understand not voting to close someone's first question, but upvoting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x+\left(x\times\left(\frac{20}{100}\right)\right)=600$$

$$x+\left(x\times\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\right)=600$$

$$x+ \frac{x}{5}=600$$

$$5x+ {x}=600 * 5$$

$$6x=3000$$

$$x=500$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation: x + (x($\frac{20}{100}$)) = 600, If your trying to find what X is equal too.

solution:

$\rightarrow$ x + (x($\frac{1}{5}$) = 600 by reducing the fraction

$\rightarrow$ x + $\frac{x}{5}$ = 600

$\rightarrow$ $\frac{x}{5}$ = 600 - x

$\rightarrow $ x = 3,000 - 5x by multiply 5 to both sides

$\rightarrow$ 6x = 3,000

$\rightarrow$ x = 500 by dividing 6 to both sides.....

finally x = 500.